# How to simultaneously select adjacent element before and after it using jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, jquery-selectors

when i click on `li.active` the 2 adjacent elements before and after it are activated.

class= active is not fixed it moves and repeats when it reaches the end element (I'm applying in slider)

Please note: I can't use eq() as the current active element will change dynamically on every mouse click.

```
$("span#ccc").click(function(){
        $("li.item").removeClass("aa");
        $("li.item.active").removeClass("active").nextAll().eq(1).toggleClass("aa");
        $("li.item.active").removeClass("active").next().prevAll().eq(0).toggleClass("aa");
    });
```

html:

```
<span id="cccc"></span>
<ul class="container">
    <li class="item">aa</li>
    <li class="item">aa</li>
    <li class="item">aa</li>
    <li class="item active">aa</li>
    <li class="item">aa</li>
    <li class="item">aa</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `.prev()` and `.next()`?

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava I have tried but it's failed

Answer (score 0):

here is an example, you can do whatever you need with both elements, for example purpose i changed the color of the text.

```js
$('.active').click(function(){
  $('.aaa').removeClass('aaa');
  $(this).removeClass('active');
  $(this).prev().addClass('aaa');
  $(this).next().addClass('aaa', 'active');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="container">
    <li class="item">aa click me</li>
    <li class="item">aa click me</li>
    <li class="item">aa click me</li>
    <li class="item active">aa click me</li>
    <li class="item">aa click me</li>
    <li class="item">aa click me</li>
</ul>
```

EDIT:
After your message i edit the code as you said.

Comment: class= active is not fixed it moves and repeats when it reaches the end element (I'm applying in slider).

Comment: i didnt use the class active. You need to be more clear about what you need.

Comment: i am animating when clicking on slider then active class will be active on next element, then i need element before and after li.active automatically add 1 class="aa", it will be repeated when class =active works. Thanks!